# Would adding a stack to a 2-stack Turing machine allow it to recognize more languages?

Tags: turing-machines

I don't think it should because a third stack would be superfluous. The machine could just reuse the first stack after it uses the second right?

I'm just beginning to learn about Turing machines, so any help appreciated!

Comment: The idea would be to prove that anything you can do with a 3-stack machine can be simulated by a 2-stack machine.

Comment: A two-stack automaton is equivalent in power to a Turing Machine; adding a third stack won't give you any more power.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforwardly boring way to see why a three-tape and one-tape machine are the same:

- A two-tape TM is equivalent to a one-tape TM.
- A three-tape TM is equivalent to a two-tape TM with an extra tape.
- Therefore, it's equivalent to a one-tape TM with an extra tape— that is, a two-tape TM.
- Therefore, it's equivalent to a one-tape TM.

Maybe a clearer way to say it is that you can simulate a one-tape TM on a three-tape TM (use one of the three tapes to write down the current state of the simulated one-tape TM).  You can also, maybe surprisingly, simulate a $k$-tape TM using only a one-tape TM. (The trick is that at any given moment, the $k$ tapes only have finite amounts of information on them, so you can write that all down on a single tape with $\mathtt{\#}$ symbols to separate the contents of different tapes, and dots to indicate where the $k$ tape-heads are located.)  This means that a $k$-tape machine and a one-tape machine are equivalent.